# AWS get last 6 month images from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

i have many images stored in AWS s3.

i just want to download the last 6 month images only anyhow. using shell script or aws cli.

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "mybucket" --prefix "some/prefix" --query "Contents[?LastModified>=`2018-08-22`].{Key: Key}"
```

i can list all the object 6 month using this command now how i can i download.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the output to download the matching files in that way

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket  --output text --prefix some/prefix  --query "Contents[?LastModified>='2018-08-22'].{Key: Key}" | xargs -I {} echo aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/{} .
```

When you pipe, using |, you are using the output of a command to run the next command.

Comment: Thanks actually i wanted to copy aws s3 data to gcp so used another command which will sync data instead of downloading and uplaoding.